# How to use grep to search only in a specific file types?

Tags: grep

I have a lot of files and I want to find where is `MYVAR`.

I'm sure it's in one of *.yml* files but I can't find in the `grep` manual how to specify the filetype.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
grep -rn --include=*.yml "MYVAR" your_directory
```

please note that grep is case sensitive by default (pass -i to tell to ignore case), and accepts Regular Expressions as well as strings.

Comment: Worth of mention that at least ZShell requires command argument `*.yml` to be quoted: `grep -rn --include="*.yml" "MYVAR" your_directory` Otherwise one will face no matches found error. More about issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/24197797/12172310]

Answer (score 5):

You don't give grep a filetype, just a list of files. Your shell can expand a pattern to give grep the correct list of files, though:

```
$ grep MYVAR *.yml
```

If your `.yml` files aren't all in one directory, it may be easier to up the ante and use `find`:

```
$ find -name '*.yml' -exec grep MYVAR {} \+
```

This will find, from the current directory and recursively deeper, any files ending with .yml. It then substitutes that list of files into the pair of braces `{}`. The trailing `\+` is just a special `find` delimiter to say the `-exec` switch has finished. The result is matching a list of files and handing them to grep.

Answer (score 3):

If all your .yml files are in one directory, then cd to that directory, and then ...

```
grep MYWAR *.yml
```

If all your .yml files are in multiple directories, then cd to the top of those directories, and then ...

```
grep MYWAR `find . -name \*.yml`
```

If you don't know the top of those directories where your .yml files are located and want to search the whole system ...

```
grep MYWAR `find / -name \*.yml`
```

The last option may require root privileges to read through all directories.

The ` character above is the one that is located along with the ~ key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name \*.yml -exec grep -Hn MYVAR {} \;
```