# grep --include command doesn't work in OSX Zsh

Tags: macos, grep, zsh

I am following the best answer on [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-in-linux/16957078#16957078) to search string in my project.

This is my command `grep --include=*.rb -rnw . -e "pattern"`

Zsh tells me that `zsh: no matches found: --include=*.rb`

It seems that grep doesn't  support `--include` option.

When I type `grep --help`, it returns

```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

no `--include` here.

Is my grep version too old? Or is there something wrong with my command?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

FreeBSD/macOS `grep` *does* support the `--include` option (see `man grep`; it's unfortunate that the *command-line* help (`grep -h`) doesn't list this option), but **your problem is that the option argument, `*.rb`, is *unquoted***.

As a result, it is *your shell*, `zsh`, that *attempts to pathname-expand `--include=*.rb` up front*, and fails, because the current directory contains no files with names matching glob pattern `*.rb`.
`grep` never even gets to execute.

**Since your intent is to pass `*.rb` *unmodified to `grep`*, you must *quote* it**:

```
grep --include='*.rb' -rnw . -e "pattern"
```

**To include *multiple* globs**:

- Pass an `--include` option *for each*; e.g.:

  ```
  grep --include='*.rb' --include=='*.h*' -rnw . -e "pattern"
  ```
- Alternatively, **in shells that support *brace expansion*** - notably `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` - you can let your *shell* create these multiple options for you, as follows - *note the **selective quoting*** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121121/45375) for a detailed explanation):

  ```
  grep '--include=*.'{rb,'h*'} -rnw . -e "pattern"
  ```

Comment: Still can't fix the pattern
`grep 'pattern' -rIn '--include=*.{c*,h*}'``

Comment: @linzuojian, you're trying to use _brace expansion_, which (a) only _some_ shells support and (b) only if used _unquoted_. `grep` itself does _not_ understand this notation. Please see my update, which shows how to use brace expansion properly, and links to an answer with background information.

Answer (score 3):

If your `grep` does not support `--include`, and you don't want to install GNU `grep` just for this, there are a number of portable ways to perform the same operation. Off the top of my head, try

```
find . -type f -name '*.rb' -exec grep -nw "pattern" /dev/null {} \;
```

The `find` command traverses the directory (like `grep -r`) looking for files named `*.rb` (like the `--include` option) and the `/dev/null` is useful because `grep` shows a slightly different output format when you run it on multiple files.

This is slightly inefficient because it runs a separate `grep` for each file. If it's too slow, look into `xargs` (or use `find -exec ... {} \+` instead of `... {} \;` if your `find` supports that). This is a very common task; you should easily find thousands of examples.

You might also want to consider [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/) which is a popular and somewhat more user-friendly alternative. It is self-contained, so "installation" amounts to copying it to your `$HOME/bin`.

Comment: No: FreeBSD _also_ supports `--include`; it's just not listed in the _command-line_ help (but is in `man grep`); the OP's issue is the use of _unquoted_ glob `*.rb`. To avoid the inefficiency of multiple `grep` invocations, simply use `+` instead of `\;`, which gives you `xargs`-like behavior: `find . -type f -name '*.rb' -exec grep -nw "pattern" {} +`. Thanks for the `ack` tip - hadn't heard of it.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  I was unsure of what's supported on `osx` and what `zsh` brings into the picture.  Added `find ... -exec ... \+` to the answer; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My pleasure; you say regarding the `+` feature: `if your find supports that`; actually, it is part of POSIX - see http://man.cx/find. Would you mind modifying your introduction to no longer suggest that _only_ GNU `grep` supports `--include`?

Comment: Standard or not, I have boxes where GNU `find` is so old as to not support `-exec ... \+` (GNU find 4.1.20, Debian 3.1 [sic])

Comment: Interesting, thanks for letting me know. (A tiny aside: the `\ ` in `\;` is solely needed to protect `;` from interpretation by the _shell_ (as a command separator) - The `\ ` gets "eaten" by the shell and `find` only sees `;`. Since `+` is not special to the shell, it needn't be escaped that way (though it doesn't do any harm either), so `-exec ... {} +` will do. However, I can see that someone might choose to still use it for symmetry and not having to remember special cases.)